The error term of ternary-Goldbach problem
Are there some results give the $X$ power saving of the error term in Ternary Goldbach problem, not just the $\log$ power saving?

This is achievable for function fields (even for the binary Goldbach problem) but seems out of reach over the integers.

Thank you so much. ^-^

Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now. Regarding high-level tags, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1075/

Improving the error beyond an arbitrary log power saving would require one to show that there do not exist Landau-Siegel zeros, as one can show that if one exists, one can get an asymptotic with a better error, but with a secondary error term dependent on the exceptional zero.
